Jupyter Lab/Notebook shows illegible axis labels for ggplot2 graphs, but pdf/png exports are fine
I am running an R kernel on Jupyter Notebook, and ggplot2 has suddenly started displaying words as piles of superimposed letters:
The Jupyter output:

However, when I save identical graphs as pdfs or pngs, the graphs display fine:
The png() output:

This instance of Jupyter is built in an Anaconda environment running on a Linux server. The behavior described above is new -- I did not have this problem a few days ago in the same environment. I think I did something that messed up the Jupyter display settings, but I cannot figure out what. I have tried the following:

deleting the environment, running conda clean -a and reinstalling the environment.
running Jupyter Lab and Notebook in different browsers
changing the Jupyter plot mimetype with options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')
deleting and regenerating the .jupyter/ directory
running ggplot2 in different notebooks and different Anaconda environments with R installed

None of these have produced different results. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as having to run png() to get images is the whole reason I am running Jupyter instead of R in command line.
Here's the test code I used in the examples:
library(ggplot2)
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")

ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()

png("midwest.png")
ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
dev.off()

Here's my session info:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /homes/weghofx/miniconda3/envs/monocle3/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.27.so;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] crayon_1.5.2      vctrs_0.6.5       cli_3.6.2         rlang_1.1.3      
 [5] generics_0.1.3    Cairo_1.6-2       jsonlite_1.8.8    labeling_0.4.3   
 [9] glue_1.7.0        colorspace_2.1-0  htmltools_0.5.8.1 IRdisplay_1.1    
[13] IRkernel_1.3.2    scales_1.3.0      fansi_1.0.6       grid_4.3.3       
[17] evaluate_0.23     munsell_0.5.1     tibble_3.2.1      fastmap_1.1.1    
[21] base64enc_0.1-3   lifecycle_1.0.4   compiler_4.3.3    dplyr_1.1.4      
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3   pbdZMQ_0.3-11     digest_0.6.35     R6_2.5.1         
[29] tidyselect_1.2.0  repr_1.1.7        utf8_1.2.4        pillar_1.9.0     
[33] magrittr_2.0.3    withr_3.0.0       uuid_1.2-0        tools_4.3.3      
[37] gtable_0.3.4 


UPDATE: A conda environment built with the command mamba create -n env conda-forge::r-base conda-forge::r-essentials renders the plots correctly in Jupyter, but the command mamba create -n env conda-forge::r-base conda-forge::r-essentials bioconda::r-monocle3 does not. So I suppose the issue is that the monocle3 bioconda package changes some dependency that results in the garbled text.
